# Can I insert a program between login and explorer shell in Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, credential-providers, gina

I was going to ask this in superuser but it is related to C/C++ and Win32 programming so I'll ask it here. I'm looking to add a step between user login and the Windows shell for Windows 7+. These are the things I've researched and tried with limited success:

1. `MSGINA` Stub, which seems like it would work perfectly but was discontinued as of Windows Vista so I can't use this.
2. I've looked at custom `Windows Credential Providers` but I'm not entirely sure this will do what I want (launch an application after login and before the windows shell).
3. A (semi) custom shell which would do what I need then launch the normal Windows shell (explorer.exe).

Option 3 has gotten me the closest but my problem is that I can't start explorer.exe as a shell if I've created the `HKLM\...\Winlogon:Shell` registry value pointing to my program. I could create the `Shell` value in `HKCU` then change it to `explorer.exe` before quitting and launching explorer then restoring the value to my program. This would work but is not as secure as using `HKLM`. In this case, I can't even use `HKLM` as my program is being executed in the current user's context and the user does not have write permissions to that key.

Are there any creative ways that I can do this or any other possibilities that I'm missing? Option 2 above didn't seem to be viable but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Isn't this what [GINA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_identification_and_authentication) is/was for?

Comment: @UweKeim Yes, it is and it would work perfectly but I mention in the question that as of Windows Vista and all versions after Vista have [discontinued](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_identification_and_authentication#End_of_life) GINA and it will no longer work, in fact the `msgina.dll` file doesn't even exist on Windows version from Vista up to 10. The replacement for GINA is the new `Credential Providers` but I'm not sure that will work properly since they handle things differently.

Comment: Maybe(!) the "_…add a step between user login and the Windows shell…_" is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/133056) and if you explain what you actually want to achieve, someone has an alternative idea on how to reach the actual goal.

Comment: @UweKeim I worded my question deliberately and is this way because I cannot get into details as to what I'm trying to accomplish due to company NDAs and Intellectual Property laws (not my company but I'm limited in what I can say). The most I can say is that I need to run a program after login but before explorer.exe starts and prevent explorer.exe from starting until my program is done. I don't believe this is an XY problem since there was a clear solution with `GINA` which can no longer be used.

Comment: are you try [userinit](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc939862.aspx) ? - `You can change the value of this entry to add or remove programs. For example, to have a program run before the Windows Explorer user interface starts,...`

Comment: @RbMm Just tested that and it actually works quite nicely, thanks for the info on `userinit` If you add it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like [RbMm's answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42051869/886887) but for completeness, another option is a [Credential Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374792(v=vs.85).aspx).

(Note: a Credential Manager is not the same thing as a Credential Provider.)

Using a Credential Manager might be preferable to using userinit in any of the following scenarios:

- You want to run code with elevated privileges.
- Your code needs to run at a very early stage in logon, e.g., before roaming profiles are loaded.
- You need the user's password.

Some reasons you might *not* want to use a Credential Manager:

- It runs as a DLL inside `winlogon` so you need to be particularly careful that your code is correct.
- Depending on what you're doing, it might be *too* early in the logon sequence. :-)
- It doesn't run in the user's context.  (There is a way around this, but it's pretty hacky.)

Comment: That might be something I need to move to if userinit doesn't work out, as it stands the user could quickly press `ctrl+shift+escape` to access the task manager before the program loads and blocks it so your solution might be more preferable down the road. Thanks for the great suggestion!

Comment: I'm not sure offhand whether or not control-shift-escape will work while `userinit` is running.  I guess if you put a long delay in your program it would be easy to test. :-)  Even if it does, though, there might be a way to disable it, so don't give up too quickly!  If you eventually decide you do need to try using a Credential Manager instead, let me know and I can email you a copy of my code to serve as a reference point.  My email address is in my profile.

Comment: Did you mean returning a program to run from `NPLogonNotify`? Why is it hacky? That's exactly what the notification is for. I'm not sure if that's synchronous though. The "hacky" thing I can think of is doing the equivalent of calling `OpenTokenByLogonId` on your own and then calling `CreateProcessAsUser`. That's a little hacky, but it doesn't sound like a big deal. Or did you mean something else? What I don't like about this approach is that it's using a feature (credential managers - all the MPR and networking stuff) for something that's really unrelated. But if there's no other option...

Comment: @conio: the "hacky" approach I was thinking of is to use the username and password you're given and use them to launch a new process in the user's context.  I'm not sure whether you can use `OpenTokenByLogonId` in a credential manager, because you don't have a `SpInitialize` function to receive the dispatch table pointer.  `WTSQueryUserToken` might work I guess, I've never tried.

Comment: Good point about returning a logon script, that's an option I'd forgotten about.  I don't know when exactly it runs though. @conio

Comment: This was definitely the way to implement what I was asking. The only issue I've come across is the `low level keyboard hook` to block all keyboard events does not work for some reason (works everywhere else, just not within the `Credential Manager`).

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Well, yes. That's why I said "*doing the **equivalent** of calling `OpenTokenByLogonId` **on your own***" rather than "*calling `OpenTokenByLogonId`*". Off the top of my head I see no reason why wouldn't `WTSQueryUserToken` work.

Comment: @conio: there's a potential timing issue.  During logon, the kernel must associate the token with the Remote Desktop session somehow (so that it knows which token to return when WTSQueryUserToken is called) and I don't know whether that happens before or after the credential manager is called.  I'd guess before, but that's just a guess.

Answer (score 3):

I think that best way for insert a program between login and explorer shell in Windows is register own application under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon` : [`Userinit`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc939862.aspx)

default `userinit.exe` run exactly between login and shell and can be customized:

> For example, to have a program run before the Windows Explorer user
>   interface starts, substitute the name of that program for Userinit.exe
>   in the value of this entry, then include instructions in that program
>   to start Userinit.exe.